# Using the compare parameters outside the if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have seend the following code...

```
var xhr = $.ajax({...});
xhr && xhr.abort && xhr.abort();
ok(xhr, "XHR object is not null or undefined");
```

and struggling to make sense of the second line `xhr && xhr.abort && xhr.abort();`

I would like to understand what it means please.

definition of `ok( bool , string )`

Comment: It's hard to say what the ok function does without any code...

Comment: This is an example of short-circuit evaluation. It evaluates from left to right, only doing whats on the right of the `&&` if the part before the `&&` returns true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
xhr && xhr.abort && xhr.abort();
```

Could be re-written as

```
if (xhr) {
   if (xhr.abort) {
       xhr.abort();
   }
}
```

That is, if `xhr` is defined (not 'falsy'), and if `xhr` has the `abort` key defined, then call `xhr.abort();`

If the line were instead:

```
xhr.abort();
```

Then if `xhr` is `undefined`, then a `ReferenceError` will be thrown. If `xhr.abort` is not a function (or `undefined`), then a `TypeError` will be thrown.

Comment: I see that is clever, so a short hand of the if statement right?

Comment: @Val yes, you'll see it a lot in scripting languages. `bar && foo()` is also common, where you execute `foo()` on the condition that `bar` is 'not falsy'. i.e. **not** `undefined`, `false`, `""`, `null`.

Answer (score 0):

The second line is equivalent to:

```
if (xhr && xhr.abort && typeof xhr.abort === 'function') {
    xhr.abort();
}
```

The `QUnit` check will then fail if the first part of the previous statement fails (meaning xhr was never defined or it was `null`).

Comment: **Not equivalent**, && implicitly casts to `Boolean`, so you're checking against 'falsy' values, not necessarily a function.

Comment: Yeah but otherwise if we just check for xhr.abort being defined and we try to invoke it without being a function we would get an error.

Comment: @KonstantinD-Infragistics The code that is in the OP does not check if `xhr.abort` is a function though. It only checks that it exists. Therefore, the second line and what you wrote are not equivelant.

Comment: @JeffShaver I can see that. The thing is that the second line would not error because it would turn the error into a boolean (false). If we want to create the equivalent code that does not error, then we would need to add a check for a function as well is what I am saying, because if we don't then the code would never get to the QUnit assert - it would fail at an earlier point. :)